# Finding an element in html page using selenium module in python

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I have to find **Input Tag** for **id** of a web page in the following HTML code using python **Selenium**:

> **NOTE: I was not able to paste the code because of its complexity so sorry for that. [Here](https://www.icloud.com/) is the page to look out the complete HTML Tree.**

I want to insert username to the mentioned below input tag:

```
<input type="text" id="appleId" can-field="accountName" autocomplete="off" 
autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-required="true" 
required="required" aria-labelledby="appleIdFieldLabel" spellcheck="false" 
autofocus="" ($focus)="appleIdFocusHandler()" 
($keyup)="appleIdKeyupHandler()" ($blur)="appleIdBlurHandler()" class="si-
text-field form-textbox " placeholder="Apple&nbsp;ID">
```

Currently, I am using mentioned below code by the means of element's **xpath** but it's returning an empty list:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.icloud.com')
time.sleep(20)
ele = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="appleId"]')
# ele.send_keys('abc@icloud.com')
print ele
```

**Result**: `[]`

I have tried every other **find** functions too but could not get any results.

Comment: What do you mean by you are not getting in results? Is the field empty? If it's empty as your code suggests, then isn't it pulling the correct result?

Comment: and why are you using xpath if there is an ID attribute?  Why not just use the appropriate find_element_by_ID?  Also are you aware you are using the plural of "element", "elements".  SO it's pulling a "list", which means you'll need to use an index on "ele".

Comment: Yes but it is not sending in the text I'm sending with this command `ele.send_keys('abc@icloud.com')` @IamBatman

Comment: Because ID attribute is not working either! and yes if use this `ele[0].send_keys('abc@icloud.com')`  it is also throwing an error @IamBatman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authorization form located inside an `iframe`. To be able to handle input fields, you should switch to that `iframe`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.icloud.com')

wait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("auth-frame"))
account_name = wait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "appleId")))
account_name.send_keys('abc@icloud.com')
```

Comment: LOL, Andersson to the rescue again.

Comment: Tried running the suggested code but it is throwing the following error: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"appleId"}`

Comment: Find the iframe by it's tagname or id, then put that element in between driver.switch_to_frame(element).

Comment: I think Andersson's way is a lil' more of overkill, but I'm sure it works fine.  We shouldn't have to write your code for you, yet just give you the direction in which to go.  Yet what do I know.

Comment: Neatly done mate really saved my butt thank you so muchhhh. @Andersson

Comment: Yes, I didn't know that you have to switch to the iframe. (kind of new to selenium) but thank you @IamBatman

Comment: Well now you know.  :)  If something is in an Iframe, it's basically another webpage entirely and you'll need to set focus to it, same goes for popup windows or separate tabs.

Comment: oh okay, good to learn that.
that's why I love StackOverflow haha, Thank you again @IamBatman